# flexbox and container widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I have a strange issue,
I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then I have this CSS

```
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {  
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    padding: 50px 20px 20px;
}

.flex-column {
    background-color: pink;

    width: auto;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 280px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.box {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

If I use it like that, the content all tries to fit in the **rows** width, which is not what I want. I would like the row to expand (and present a scrollbar) depending on how much content is in it.

Now, by accident I noticed that if I add the **flex-column** class to the row, it fixes it (sort of). You can see with the background colours that it isn't doing everything correctly, but the side effect is that it actually works the way I want it to.

My question is how can I get it to wrap the row around the content but still have the scroll bar?

Here is the codepen to show what I currently have.

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/waPoQo

if you remove the **flex-column** class from the row, you will see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use flexbox? You can do it without it. I have posted a flex and a non-flex example. If you want to use flex, you have to make sure you that you have a block container element around your flex element with `overflow:scroll`. Also your main flex element inside your container needs to be set to `float` so that it will properly expand horizontally to include your `inline-block` child elements.

**Non-Flex Example:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
    background-color: red !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px 20px 20px;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.flex-column {
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
    width: 280px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.box {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Flex Example:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
}

.row {
    background-color: red !important;
    display: flex;
    padding: 50px 20px 20px;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
}

.flex-column {
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
    width: 280px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.box {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```